# MySQL word+word search

Tags: mysql, search, select, concatenation

I have two tables: Dictionary, Names.
Both tables have large number of rows (like 200.000).

Columns in Dictionary: id, word

Columns in Names: id, name

I need to select all Names which are Dictionary.word+Dictionary.word (something like concatenation of same column, for all variation)

Also, I need fast query, not something that would take hours to load...
About this speed - I would be satisfied if requirements are set to something like "min 5 chars" for column/word comparision...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM `Names` `n`
INNER JOIN `Dictionary` `d`
ON `d`.`word` IS NOT NULL
AND (`n`.`name` LIKE CONCAT(`d`.`word`,`d`.`word`));
```

Update:

```
SELECT * FROM `Names` `n`
INNER JOIN `Dictionary` `d1`
INNER JOIN `Dictionary` `d2`
        ON `n`.`name` = CONCAT(`d1`.`word`,`d2`.`word`) 
        OR `n`.`name` LIKE CONCAT(`d1`.`word`,`_%`) 
        OR `n`.`name` LIKE CONCAT(`d2`.`word`,`_%`)
```

Comment: But, all of this answeres gives results only for names which are made of same word+word... only JohnJohn and similar are selected. I need JohnHouse as well... you know what I mean ?

Comment: I think with this query it will also match "John"

Comment: @Abhay: Yes, which is what he asked.

Comment: @Shef: I think Darko needs word+word, e.g. JohnJohn or JohnHouse, as it also seems from the title. I'm not sure if he also needs "John"

Comment: @Abhay, @Darko: Added `_%`, which will match `John` + one character. If it's just `John`, it won't match. :)

Comment: @Shef: Ok, thanks. But that isn't a good idea to have so many JOIN conditions and the LIKE operator might be heavy as well for the JOIN

Comment: @Abhay: Give him a solution then. This will do the job just fine. I don't see any better solution to this problem. If you have a better optimized query, write it, don't just downvote for no reason.

Comment: @Shef: I think I didn't but I'm sorry if I sounded rude. I just wanted to share a point about the query; nothing else.

Comment: Hello, sorry for a delay in response... I don't need "John", just all word+word combinations...

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
SELECT `N`.`name`
FROM `Names` `N`
INNER JOIN `Dictionary` `D` ON `N`.`name` = CONCAT(`D`.`word`, `D`.`word`);
```

New query:

```
SELECT `N`.`name`
FROM `Names` `N`
INNER JOIN `Dictionary` `D`
INNER JOIN `Dictionary` `D1`
WHERE `N`.`name` = CONCAT(`D`.`word`, `D1`.`word`);
```

Comment: @Darko: please see that you have the right indexes on `Names.name` and `Dictionary`.`word` columns

Comment: But, all of this answeres gives results only for names which are made of same word+word... only JohnJohn and similar are selected. I need JohnHouse as well... you know what I mean ?

Answer (score 0):

this tries to get the answer using the index that is on d.word.

```
SELECT *
FROM Names n
JOIN Dictionary d1
JOIN Dictionary d2
WHERE 
    LEFT(n.name, LENGTH(n.name)/2) = d1.word
AND RIGHT(n.name, LENGTH(n.name)/2) = d2.word
AND n.name = CONCAT(d1.word, d2.word);
```

Comment: Working fine. But, all of this answeres gives results only for names which are made of same word+word... only JohnJohn and similar are selected. I need JohnHouse as well... you know what I mean ?

Comment: oooooh. didn't realize that's what you wanted. 1 sec.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about speed at all:

```
SELECT n.*
FROM Names AS n
  JOIN Dictionary AS d1
    ON n.name LIKE CONCAT(d1.word, '%')
  JOIN Dictionay AS d2
    ON d1.id <= d2.id
WHERE n.name = CONCAT(d1.word, d2.word))
```